# Div in the center?

Tags: css

```
<li class="row">
    <div class="small-6 column center">
    <img src="test.jpg">
</div>
    <div class="small-6 column center">
        <p>hello</p>
    </div>
 </li>
```

I wish to make the hello p in the centre (vertically and horizontally) of it's column.

I do this with the styles:

```
 p{
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

The problem is, the second column is not the same height as the first column. How can I make it so that it is?

Here's my styles for columns:

```
.row{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;

    .column{
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        display: block;
        background: yellow;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 10px;
    }

        .small-1 {
            width: 8.33333%; }

        .small-2 {
            width: 16.66667%;}

        .small-3 {
            width: 25%;}

        .small-4 {
            width: 33.33333%; }

        .small-5 {
            width: 41.66667%; }

        .small-6 {
            width: 50%; }

        .small-7 {
            width: 58.33333%; }

        .small-8 {
            width: 66.66667%; }

        .small-9 {
            width: 75%; }

        .small-10 {
            width: 83.33333%; }

        .small-11 {
            width: 91.66667%; }

        .small-12 {
            width: 100%; }


}

.pull-left{
    float: left;
}
.pull-right{
    float: right;
}

.center{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I'm not using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
.small-6 {
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

or like this

```
.small-6 {
    height: 60px;
}
```

change 60 to whatever works for you

Comment: Seems a bit hacky. Content is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options here.

1. Use JS to create equal height boxes - Foundation has an example of that [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html)
2. Make the row "cleared" and stretch the text box to the top and bottom of it like this:

   .box-content{
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       left: 50%;
       margin: 0;
       -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
       transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   }

http://jsfiddle.net/ga24a/3/

Now its rather fragile when the text becomes larger - it cannot force the row container to be larger, only the img box can.

1. Use the new hyper super duber FLEX :D

http://jsfiddle.net/3n7Dj/1/

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
    ...
}
```